# Failing to set bundle identifier from .xcconfig for automatic signing

Tags: xcode

Can't figure this out, please help.

I have a project in Xcode 10.3 with dev, staging, prod environments using one scheme and one .xcconfig file per environment. I followed this guide:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/let-s-setup-your-ios-environments. (Thanks Thoughbot!)

Everything is working, except one issue:

I want Xcode to automatically manage signing. For that I need bundle identifier in Targets > General > Identity to be set from the right .xcconfig whenever I change the scheme. It's not. Instead it always picks up $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) from the **first** configuration in Project > Configurations.

When I run the app, it does pick up $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) from the correct .xcconfig.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

In the screenshots below from a sample app, Bundle Identifier in the first screenshot should be "prod", instead it's "dev".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]